# What should I do about the March 12th 2013 blockchain fork?

Tags: blockchain, blockchain-fork, news-coverage, march-2013-fork

[Reddit/r/bitcoin](http://www.reddit.com/r/bitcoin) is flooding with news that the Bitcoin blockchain has forked, in that versions 0.7 and 0.8 are accepting different blockchains. What does this mean for the users?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Gavin Andreson has tweeted this:
https://twitter.com/gavinandresen/status/311290936527298561

The bitcointalk post linked by Gavin is a post by Peter Wuille, which says this:

*Hello everyone,*

*there is an emergency right now: the block chain has split between 0.7+earlier and 0.8 nodes. I'll explain the reasons in a minute, but this is what you need to know now:*

- *After a discussion on #bitcoin-dev, it seems trying to get everyone on the old chain again is the least risky solution.*
- *If you're a miner, please do not mine on 0.8 code. Stop, or switch back to 0.7. BTCGuild is switching to 0.7, so the old chain will get a majority hash rate soon.*
- *If you're a merchant: please stop processing transactions until the chains converge.*
- *If you're on 0.7 or older, the client will likely tell you that you need to upgrade. Do not follow this advise - the warning should go away as soon as the old chain catches up.*
- *If you are not a merchant or a miner, don't worry.*

[An announcement has also been made at bitcoin.org](http://bitcoin.org/chainfork.html).

Comment: What about miners against public pools? I'm assuming we should check the pool website for status, but is there anything specific we can do?

Comment: @JedDaniels, yes, you could also check bitcointalk to find a pool operator that is clearly running the correct version.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a user, Don't do anything, including transactions.

If you are a miner, Stop mining on 0.8.

If you are a merchant, Don't do anything, including transactions.

Comment: Poor wording.  E.g. merchants need to do something, unless they sell stuff by hand: turn off their automated bitcoin processing.